# Rails + Heroku + RSpec : How to control logging

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, heroku, rspec

I have a Ruby on Rails 3.2 application which runs on Heroku. I'm using RSpec for my test suite.

When I started, I just used statements such as

```
p "Order completed at #{Time.now.to_s}"
```

to generate logs. I did this because Heroku uses its magical jiggery-pokery to divert all logs to STDOUT anyways.

However, my test suite prints all kinds of logs to STDOUT now, and it is very distracting. I would like those logs to appear when the application is deployed to Heroku, but I don't want to see them on my STDOUT output along with my RSpec output.

Is there a way to divert STDOUT to a file such as log/test.log, or alternatively, use a logging API which will do what I want?

Comment: The correct way to log is by using the `Rails.logger`, not using `p`. You can also create a custom logger that writes wherever you want, and defaults to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not intimately familiar with the particularities of Heroku's implementation, but you should be able to choose your own file for logging without problem.  If they made logging to a file impossible I would be incredibly surprised.  You can define your logger in environment.rb differently for prod (ie Heroku) and dev with something like the following in the appropriate conditional:

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
Rails.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
```

or in your Initializer like so:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
```

Note that you have lots of options for your logger, for example you can use Log4r instead of the built-in logger.

Check out the [RoR Debugging Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger) for more

Comment: Then you are incredibly surprised. Because Heroku provides a distributed and scalable server architecture, they figured that it would be easier to do that if they didn't provide a trustworthy file system. You can read & write to a file, but if the heroku container is deleted, the file will be gone. And you have no guarantee that a file will be equally accessible to all containers in your application, mainly because they could be on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the gem only in your production group to avoid this issue.

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```